# Exception in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I converted a class library from windows phone 7 to windows phone 8 version. but while run time i am getting the exception "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll" XAML parser exception is occuring.  The above Exception is occurring while initializing the usercontrol in the library and it code is below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsPhone.LogicClient"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">       
        <controls:Pivot Name="OPivot">
            <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" DoubleTap="TextBlock_DoubleTap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Please note there is no such exception in windows phone 7.1 source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code in test app and it works
only change i need to do to convert :

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
```

to

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

And check that you don't miss to enable any required capability in you App Manifest